# Input on where and how I can make improvements on my randomizer

Tags: java, random

As my title states I'm just looking for a little input on how I can improve one of my side projects when I'm not doing my CS assignments. All my program is, is a primitive randomizer for Battlefield 4 classes and weapons (because I can never choose what to play). But since I am still new to java (second semester in) I was wondering if someone more experienced than I could shoot a few concepts my way on how I can make this better, if not more re-useable for other things. Here is my driver:

```
package BattlefieldClassRandomizer;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class BF4ClassRandomizerDriver {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
       BattlefieldClass random = new BattlefieldClass();
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
       int numberOfClasses;
       do{ 
           System.out.print("Choose how many times to randomize: ");
           numberOfClasses = keyboard.nextInt();
       } while (numberOfClasses <= 0);
        System.out.println("Here are your soldiers");
        for (int r = 0; r < numberOfClasses; r++) {
            random.randomizeChance();
            random.classSelection();
            random.randomizeChance();
            random.weaponSelection();
            System.out.println("Class:" + random.getClassType()+ "; Weapon:" + random.getWeaponType());
        }

       }
    }
```

And here is the my entity class (clunky, I know):

```
    package BattlefieldClassRandomizer;
//System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
public class BattlefieldClass {

    private String classType;
    private double chance;
    private String weaponType;

    BattlefieldClass() {
        classType = "Assault";
        chance = 0.0;
        weaponType = "Assault Rifle";
    }

    public String getClassType() {
        return classType;
    }

    public double getChance() {
        return chance;
    }

    public String getWeaponType() {
        return weaponType;
    }

    public void setClassType(String newClassType) {
        if ((classType.equals("Assault")) || (classType.equals("Engineer"))
                || (classType.equals("Support")) || classType.equals("Recon")) {
            classType = newClassType;
        }
    }

    public void setWeaponType(String newWeaponType) {
        if ((weaponType.equals("Assault")) || (weaponType.equals("Engineer"))
                || (weaponType.equals("Support")) || weaponType.equals("Recon")) {
            classType = newWeaponType;
        }

    }

    public void randomizeChance() {
        chance = Math.random();
    }

    public void classSelection() {
        if ((chance >= 0) && (chance < .25)) {
            classType = "Assault";
        }
        if ((chance >= .25) && (chance < .50)) {
            classType = "Engineer";
        }
        if ((chance >= .50) && (chance < .75)) {
            classType = "Support";
        }
        if (chance >= .75) {
            classType = "Recon";
        }
    }

    public void weaponSelection() {
        if ((chance >= 0) && (chance < .25) && (classType.equals("Assault"))) {
            weaponType = "Assault Rifle";
        } else if ((chance >= .25) && (chance < .50) && (classType.equals("Assault"))) {
            weaponType = "Carbine";
        } else if ((chance >= .50) && (chance < .75) && (classType.equals("Assault"))) {
            weaponType = "DMR";
        } else if ((chance >= .75) && (classType.equals("Assault"))) {
            weaponType = "Shotgun";
        }
        if ((chance >= 0) && (chance < .25) && (classType.equals("Engineer"))) {
            weaponType = "PDW";
        } else if ((chance >= .25) && (chance < .50) && (classType.equals("Engineer"))) {
            weaponType = "Carbine";
        } else if ((chance >= .50) && (chance < .75) && (classType.equals("Engineer"))) {
            weaponType = "DMR";
        } else if ((chance >= .75) && (classType.equals("Engineer"))) {
            weaponType = "Shotgun";
        }
        if ((chance >= 0) && (chance < .25) && (classType.equals("Support"))) {
            weaponType = "LMG";
        } else if ((chance >= .25) && (chance < .50) && (classType.equals("Support"))) {
            weaponType = "Carbine";
        } else if ((chance >= .50) && (chance < .75) && (classType.equals("Support"))) {
            weaponType = "DMR";
        } else if ((chance >= .75) && (classType.equals("Support"))) {
            weaponType = "Shotgun";
        }
        if ((chance >= 0) && (chance < .25) && (classType.equals("Recon"))) {
            weaponType = "Sniper Rifle";
        } else if ((chance >= .25) && (chance < .50) && (classType.equals("Recon"))) {
            weaponType = "Carbine";
        } else if ((chance >= .50) && (chance < .75) && (classType.equals("Recon"))) {
            weaponType = "DMR";
        } else if ((chance >= .75) && (classType.equals("Recon"))) {
            weaponType = "Shotgun";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Randomizechance, classSelection, and weaponSelection should be called in your constructor. Also it's generally a bad idea to initially set variables with incorrect values. If someone forgot to call the right method first, they should get a null or a NullPointerException, not an incorrect (non-random) value.

Comment: Gottchya. So it would be better for my strings to be set to null? How about my double, should that also be null, or is a default of zero acceptable?

Comment: A primitive can't be null, and a double defaults to zero. Actually, rather than setting the strings to null, I think it's common practice to simply not set  the strings. It might make sense, though, to set chance to -1, so weaponSelection() and classSelection() can detect this (in a default case at the end of a switch statement) and throw an exception. I'm not totally sure it's worth doing, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bug**

Your `setWeaponType` function sets `classType`, not `weaponType`.

You also do not check the input parameters (`newClassType` and `newWeaponType`), but `classType` and `weaponType`.

**Brackets**

I think that you use too many brackets, this makes your code harder to read. Generally, grouping complex boolean expressions with brackets is good, but you don't need to put a single expression in them (eg `(classType.equals("Support"))`).

**Public Methods**

Right now, you have to call 4 methods to use your class. Do you expect use cases where you need to call these methods separately? If not, just make them private and only create one public method (eg called `generate`).

**Extract code to function**

You do a lot of range checks in your code, so why not define a function for it:

```
// returns true if input is in between min and max (including min, excluding max).
private boolean inInterval(double input, double min, double max) {
    return input >= min && input < max;
}
```

Then your `classSelection` function would look like this:

```
public void classSelection() {
    if (inInterval(chance, 0, .25)) {
        classType = "Assault";
    } else if (inInterval(chance, 0.25, .50)) {
        classType = "Engineer";
    } else if (inInterval(chance, 0.50, .75)) {
        classType = "Support";
    } else  if (inInterval(chance, .75, 1.0)) {
        classType = "Recon";
    }
}
```

Note also that I replaced your `if`s with `else-if`s, as only one condition can be true at a time. No need to check the other once.

You can also use this function in your `weaponSelection` method.

You can do the same for the type checks:

```
private boolean isValidType(String type) {
    return  classType.equals("Assault") || classType.equals("Engineer")
            || classType.equals("Support") || classType.equals("Recon");
}
```

Then use this in your `setWeaponType` and `setClassType` functions to avoid duplicate code and to make it easier to add new types. You could also create a list or enum of types to make this a lot easier.

**Use `switch` to simplify `if` statements**

If you use a `switch`, your if statements in `weaponSelection` would look like this:

```
public void weaponSelection() {       
    switch(classType) {
        case "Assault": 
            if (inInterval(chance, 0, .25)) {
                weaponType = "Assault Rifle";
            } else if (inInterval(chance, 0.25, .50)) {
                weaponType = "Carbine";
            } else if (inInterval(chance, 0.50, .75)) {
                weaponType = "Carbine";
            } else  if (inInterval(chance, .75, 1.0)) {
                weaponType = "Shotgun";
            }
            break;
        case "Engineer":
            [...]
            break;
        case "Support":
            [...]
            break;
        case "Recon":
            [...]
            break;
    }
}
```

I think that this would be a bit cleaner and more readable.

**General structure**

Right now, your class does two things: It selects classes, and - relatively independent of this - it selects weapons.

You might consider creating two classes, a `WeaponSelector` and a `ClassSelector`.

They can both extend a common base class and share some methods (like the `inRange` and `randomizeChance` methods). You could also create an enum for the different classes. Then, your `ClassSelector` could return a value from this enum, and pass it to the `WeaponSelector`, so it can make it's choice based on it.

Comment: Why thank you! I really like the added method. That for sure will clean it up a helluva a lot, as well as the added `switch`. The second comment you made in with the "Bug" could say that again? I'm not checking the parameters but my instance variables instead? And I assume your referring to my mutators?

Comment: Right, that's what I meant. I mean, the whole point of the class type check code in `setClassType` is to check if the input is valid, right? But right now, you are checking if the current value of the field is valid instead (which it will always be as you never set it to anything invalid, so this check wouldn't be necessary). Oh, and if you use an enum for the type, you wouldn't need the check at all, because invalid input would be impossible.